# They for "he/she"

Tags: etymology, pronouns

How did the word "they" come to represent "he or she"? For example, "They forgot their coat" can be used to represent a single person of either sex.

Comment: To the mystery downvoter: It's customary to leave a brief comment explaining how the question could be improved. It's unfair to downvote and disappear mysteriously into the night, especially when there's nothing intrinsically wrong with the question (that i can see).

Comment: Aren't standard German "sie" (feminine third person) and "Sie" (polite second person singular) just two morphemes that happen to have the same phonological form?

Comment: @JamesGrossmann I believe that deserves its own question: have they always been the same, or were they 2 separate words whose pronunciation merged over time?

Comment: @JamesGrossmann Don't forget that *sie* is also the plural third person pronoun! There are all sorts of interesting syncretism patterns in pronominal paradigms.

Comment: From the WALS chapter on politeness distinctions:

*"The avoidance of direct (linguistic) reference to the addressee in the context of face-threatening utterances is the main functional motivation for developing polite referential expressions such as vous  in French, and Sie  in German. The 2pl pronoun vous  in French presumably came into use historically as a polite form of singular address because it renders the reference less direct and less specific (cf. Malsch 1987, Helmbrecht 2002, 2003)."* (http://wals.info/chapter/45)

Comment: So-called ["singular _they_" is discussed here](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/June05Eye.pdf); there is a real, verified syntactic rule. But it only works in some cases, because it has boundary conditions like every syntactic rule. People who tell you different are simply repeating what they were told in third grade.

Answer (score 2):

As usual, Wikipedia has a [great article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_they) regarding this.

Late Medieval English used "they" in the singular when the number of possible nouns was unknown or left vague on purpose by the speaker. In most other situations, then native speakers would use "he" as generic - e.g. a dog's toy was "his toy" rather than "its", and such use was sometimes used also for subjects who could potentially be either male/female.

Centuries later, when first the "Politically Correctness" movement came, and then some feminists started to deride what they deemed signs of sexism in the language, the need to get a real neuter-gender alternative to he/she resulted in expanding the use of singular they. You'll also occassionally find other words invented by some feminists ex-profeso to avoid the perceived implied otherness of the feminity, mostly in feminist literature (of course).

In other languages, the most natural way to refer to a sex-less 3rd person would be to use the equivalent of "it", but in English the distinction "male/female" has become very weak over time, whereas the distinction "animate/inanimate" is still perceived in full force - so the only time "it" can be applied to humans is when they're babies or very very young children. So instead of "A young teenage almost never uses contraception when having its first sexually intimate relationship " you get "(...) **their** first sexual (...)", as grammatically contorted as it may seem.

Some papers and writers have simply inverted the common usage of "he" as generic and instead take "she" as the generic unless maleness is needed/specified, so you get more grammatical sentences whilst avoiding perceived sexism.

Answer (score 1):

The OED says

> "In anaphoric reference to a singular noun or pronoun of undetermined gender: he or she.Especially in relation to a noun phrase involving one of the indefinite determiners or pronouns *any*, *each*, *every*, *no*, *some*, *anybody*, *anyone*, etc.
>
> This use has sometimes been considered erroneous."

with examples from circa 1375.

I think the important point for your question is the second clause: of the fifteen the examples the OED gives, all but two contain *every*, *any(body)* or *no(body)*.

If you have started with *Everybody* (for example) it is very natural to refer back with *they*, because *everybody* is in a sense plural.

I think the practice of using singular *they* without such an antecedent (i.e. when it represents a particular individual, but whose identity, and therefore whose sex, is not yet known) is much more recent, probably less than fifty years.

*Edit:* There is a huge literature on this subject: search for "singular they".

Comment: *Everybody* are in a sense singular too.